# Unit testing BlobStore create_upload_url uploads

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm using the using the GAE BlobStore API to create an upload URL, as follows:

```
self.response.write(blobstore.create_upload_url(....))
```

Everything works fine in production, but when using testbed to unit test this API, I get the following URL back:

```
http://testbed.example.com/_ah/upload/agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgDDA
```

Uploading to this URL from the test doesn't work, I get a 404. I should have initialized all stubs properly, amongst others:

```
self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
self.testbed.init_blobstore_stub()
self.testbed.init_files_stub()
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I unit test file uploads using the blobstore create_upload_url API?

Comment: What does your test look like? You likely want to be mocking the upload, rather than actually making requests in a test...

Comment: Please post the test contents where you are seeing the 404. Depending on your application needs you may want to switch to using Google Cloud Storage and the default bucket for your application. There is a free quota on the default bucket and you won't have to POST to the `blobstore.create_upload_url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments and looking at the code, I'm assuming you can't do it out of the box.

My solution to the problem is to implement the uploading myself, using the  `google.appengine.api.datastore.Get` to extract information from the session pointed to by the `create_upload_url` url.

Below is some test code. It's using `post` from WebTest, and a stub for GCS, although the latter is probably unnecessary.

```
from google.appengine.api import datastore
import uuid
import base64
import md5

def testSomething(self):
  upload_url = self.testapp.post('/path/to/create_upload_url/handler').body
  response = self.upload_blobstore_file(upload_url, "file", "myfile.txt", "MYDATA1").json
  # Test something on the response from the success handler and/or backing storage

def upload_blobstore_file(self, upload_url, field, filename, contents, type = "application/octet-stream"):
  session = datastore.Get(upload_url.split('/')[-1])
  new_object = "/" + session["gs_bucket_name"] + "/" + str(uuid.uuid4())
  self.storage_stub.store(new_object, type, contents)

  message = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Length: " + str(len(contents)) + "\r\nContent-MD5: " + base64.b64encode(md5.new(contents).hexdigest()) + "\r\nX-AppEngine-Cloud-Storage-Object: /gs" + new_object.encode("ascii") + "\r\ncontent-disposition: form-data; name=\"" + field + "\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\nX-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2015-07-17 16:19:55.531719\r\n\r\n"
  return self.testapp.post(session["success_path"], upload_files = [
  (field, filename, message, "message/external-body; blob-key=\"encoded_gs_file:blablabla\"; access-type=\"X-AppEngine-BlobKey\"")
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the http_host in the testbed:

```
self.testbed.setup_env(
        http_host='%s:%s' % (SERVER_NAME, PORT),
        overwrite=True,)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to me, you cannot directly create the blob data, instead of it blobs are created indirectly by a submitted web form or HTTP post request. For more details you can go through the document [1].

[1]  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Introducing_the_Blobstore